# How to filter out a movie on Netflix?

Tags: netflix

Is it possible to filter out a movie in Netflix, so I don't see it again, probably unless I choose otherwise?

Every time I open the Netflix website, it starts a trailer of "Godless", and I hate it.

What can be done so I don't see the trailer and hear "Christ is the power..." song again?